# Is there an orbot equivalet app for Desktop?

Tags: windows, mac, orbot

I've been using Orbot for Android for a while and having a great experience with it. I always thought it would be slow and so on.

Now, for Desktop, I can't find an equivalent to Orbot, that would behave like a VPN and route all connections via Tor regardless if I'm using the Tor browser.

I found a couple of VPN tutorials but they all rely on some external company that provides the the "connect via Tor" profile for OpenVPN or some other generic VPN app.

Is there such a thing as an Orbot for Windows/Mac?

Answer (score 1):

- [Tor Expert Bundle on Windows](https://www.torproject.org/download/tor/)
- [Tor](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-osx.html.en) for Mac
- It comes as a standard part of most Linux distributions.

These are not like Android apps. If you don't want to learn how to use a command line, then they aren't for you. If you want to take the time to learn something new, this will do it.

Answer (score 0):

No, on a desktop you have an ability to do so yourself. And - actually - mobile vendors are selling your tracing data so they can not be trusted either. In My Humble Opinion the **only** way is to use like a Single-Board-Computer like a Raspberry Pi or an Orange Pi to make a secure gateway. But - be warned - GPS/AGPS leaks are not covered here!